# Trigger an event that blocks the execution of the default code

Tags: backbone.js

I'm working on a auth based application where the user must be logged to access to a certain routes of the website. I haven't found documentation on how to accomplish this so I worked on a idea on how to solve it.

This is my function to know if a user is logged or not:

```
App.filterAuth = function(navigateTo) {
    navigateTo = typeof navigateTo !== 'undefined' ? navigateTo : '#';

    if (App.logged == false) {
        App.vent.trigger('navigate', navigateTo);
    }
};
```

My idea is that when a user is logged sets the `App.logged = true`. Then, when my router tries to execute a concrete router I can just call `App.filterAuth()`. This actually works and doing some debugging I see that everything is triggered corrected.

The problem? For example I execute this on a protected route that loads a feed of images for a user. When `App.filterAuth()` is executed I see that it tries to navigate to `#` but the execution of this feed view isn't stopped and also the view associated to my `#` route is not triggered.

Any idea on how I can improve this function that makes it work correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean the url will just navigate to `example.com/#` without any rout? Are you using `event.preventDefault()` to block any propagation?

Comment: @dbf: thanks! No, I'm not using `event.preventDefault()` because I don't know where I can fit it in my function. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not create a seperate `Backbone.Router` and instantiate it when you set `App.logged` or set-up the routes on your existing router?

Comment: @fbynite I didn't think in that option, thanks! I will try the plugin suggested and also this option you pointed. Thanks!!

Comment: @udexter, I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17985349/722238, it could be used as a solution to your problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer to question directly, but there is a backbone plugin which can help you with what you try to do: https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter

You can specify additional methods, which will be triggered before / after route code is processed. If you return false from *before* callback, router code won't be evaluated: https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter#returning-false-from-within-a-before-filter

So, you could create before filter, which could check, if route should be secured. If it is secured and user is not authenticated, you just return false and router code is not used.