# Router in backbone not handling route after initialization

Tags: backbone.js, router, backbone-routing

I have multiple routers in my app, in general way it looks like this:

```
// Start backbone.js
if (!Backbone.History.started) {
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, hashChange: false});
}

// Perform some RPC requests ...

// Depending on user role, received from the server should be created suitable router:
var router;
if (typeof app.user.role === 'manager') {
    router = new routers.manager();
} else {
    router = new routers.guest();
}
```

Problem is that after page is loaded and script is executed routers do not do. anything. They do not load route for current url automatically. So, i had to fix it this way (i am not sure that it is a right way):

```
routers.guest.initialize = routers.manager.initialize = function() {
    var defaultRoute = 'default';
    if (typeof this.routes[Backbone.history.fragment] !== 'undefined') {
        this[this.routes[Backbone.history.fragment]]();
    } else {
        this.navigate(defaultRoute, true);
    }
};
```

It is working fine, except one bug: when i use route with params, for example `/reset-password-confirm/:code` - it is unable to find in in `routes` property. I could write some more code to fix it, but i suppose that i am doing something wrong, if i have to write such things - as i understand router should handle routes just after it was created.

So, questions:

1. Why my router(s) does not handle routes for current url after it is being created? Perhaps i need to start backbone history later? (but this bug will happen again later then)
2. How it is possible to make routes with params like `/user/:id` work there?
3. Perhaps it is bad idea to re-create routers? Perhaps it is better to create all of them one time?

P.S. I've tried to create both routers and keep them, also i've trie to call backbone history start method after all routers were created.. but this didn't help :/

Comment: could you pls post your router code too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you route is declared as the following:

```
 routes : {
   '/user/:id' : 'user'
 }
```

Your `initialize` code is not working because when you initialize your router with a url such as: `/user/1234`. `Backbone.history.fragment` will be `/user/1234` (not `/user/:id`). Since the `this.routes` object doesn't have a key of `/user/1234`, your `else` clause calls the `default` route.

If you first instantiate your `router` then call `Backbone.history.start()`, you will be able to remove your router `initialize` code. When you navigate to a url as `/user/1234` your router will match the `/user/:id` route and call the `user` function.

The following should work for you without adding your `initialize` code:

```
var router = (app.user.role === 'manager') ? new routers.manager() 
                                           : new routers.guest();

Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, hashChange: false});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, seems like you're starting the backbone history before initializing any routes. That's most likely not goning to work.

The correct way of doing this type of seperation is by creating all the routes based on the role received from the server and then start the backbone history. Here's an SO thread that talks about it with code samples as well : [How to protect routes for different user groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974259/how-to-protect-routes-for-different-user-groups/17975010)

Comment: I've tried to create router before starting history.. but this does not work too. Backbone.history.start() also returns false... Thanks for your answer

Comment: @trueツ: have you tried what's mentioned in the other SO thread?

Comment: I don't care about roles now, i just create all routers before history.start(), but it does not work anyway.. Roles handling could be done in more nice way from my point of view, as said in the topic. I just can't get why it does not work :/